# How to declare a function with a default parameter before a non-default parameter in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to declare a function with a non-default (mandatory) parameter preceded by a default parameter, just as in the built-in range function: `range(start, end, step)`

Is there anyway to do that? When I try to define a function that way I get a `SyntaxError` as in `def example(a = 0, b)`

Comment: Ummm, based on what you want this function to do. I'll be able to find a way if I know what's going to be the output

Comment: @Dav_DidHu I need a function that returns the primes in a given interval, this is what I got: ```def primes_in_interval(start = 2, end):```

Comment: I've basically given up trying to fight Python and now I'm forcing the function to receive a parameter x_range (which need to be a range) `raise TypeError(f"passing a {type(x_range)} when a range is expected")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, positional arguments **must** come before keyword arguments – it's just a rule of the language.  That said, there *are* a few ways (that I wouldn't necessarily recommend) that you could write a function to get around this.

This is essentially how the built-in `range` function does what you're describing:

```
def range(*args):
    # default values
    start = 0
    step = 1

    n_args = len(args)
    if not 0 < n_args < 4:
        raise TypeError(f'range expected 1 arguments, got {n_args}')
    elif n_args == 1:
        stop = args[0]
    elif n_args == 2:
        start, stop = args
    else:
        start, stop, step = args
    
    # etc...
```

It requires arguments be passed in a specific order, then determines what variables to assign values to based on the number of arguments passed.

Or, consider the following:

```
def example(a=10, b=None):
    assert b is not None, "argument 'b' is required"
    # etc...
```

This is an even uglier solution, because:

1. you must pass `b` as a keyword argument, not a positional argument
2. The function signature doesn't give the user any indication that `b` is required – it looks like it's optional, but the function will fail if it's not explicitly passed.
3. You'd have to set the parameter's "invalid" value to something you're 100% certain no one would ever want to *actually* pass to that argument.

Unless there's a really compelling reason not to, it's best to stick to the usual format (positional arguments first, optionally followed by collecting leftover `*args`, then keyword arguments, optionally followed by collecting leftover `**kwargs`).  It's how people expect to use a function and will make your code easier to both use and read.  If there *really is* a compelling reason to deviate from that, mimic the setup of `range`.

#### edit:

re: your question about "correcting" the function signature to show certain parameter names instead of `*args`, the example above massively simplifies how the `range` built-in works. In reality, it's implemented in C and its signature/docstring are set [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4173320920706b49a004bdddd8d7108e8984e3fc/Objects/rangeobject.c#L157-L165).  It's more analogous to a class that defines a `__call__` method that gets run inside the constructor than a regular function.

Manually overriding an object's signature would be tricky (not to mention a whole lot of extra steps to avoid using the "normal" parameter order) -- you're much better off just putting the "correct" parameter names in the docstring.

There are some really, really hacky ways you could do it. E.g., you could wrap the function in a decorator that uses something like `inspect.Signature` to modify the function object. Or maybe you could convert it to a class, have it inherit from some parent class, then use a combination of `__init_subclass__` in the parent and `__new__` in the child to intercept and modify the arguments passed to the constructor.  But these solutions are so far off in left field that it's worth asking **why** there isn't a simpler way to solve this problem. In my opinion, it's because this simply isn't something you want to be doing in the first place.

Comment: Is there anyway to correct the signature of the function so it show the "correct" names of the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Default arguments *must* be last in the argument list. If you want different behavior, then you'll have to do the validation inside the function.

```
def primes_in_interval(start=2, end=None):
    assert(end is not None)
    # Rest of code.

primes_in_interval(end=10)
```

You could do something like this to get the calling convention you're looking for.

```
def primes_in_interval(end_or_start, end=None):
    if end is None:
        start = 2
        end   = end_or_start
    else:
        start = end_or_start
        end   = end
    # Rest of code.

primes_in_interval(10)      # Start will be 2 and end 10
primes_in_interval(8, 16)   # Start will be 8 and end 16
```

Comment: Is it possible to define `start` inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The way `range`'s parameters are defined is a feature of `range` being a built-in and using a different means of parsing arguments, [roughly equivalent to receiving `*args, **kwargs` and hand-parsing them](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/rangeobject.c#L77) (it rejects non-empty `kwargs` manually, but still has to accept them due to the conventions of CPython's C API). If you want to do it yourself, you can, but Python won't help:

```
def myrange(*args):
    if not args or len(args) > 3:
        raise TypeError("Expected 1-3 args")
    if len(args) == 1:
        start, step = 0, 1
        stop, = args
    else:
        start, stop, step = (args + (1,))[:3]  # Stupid trick to reduce number of cases

    # Actual work done here
```